# Extracting a single audio track from a video with multiple audio streams

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player

I have a MKV file with 4 MPEG AAC audio streams. I would like to extract one of those streams into a separate audio file, but the “Convert” feature in VLC does not seem to have an option to select the audio stream, and if I proceed, the generated file is not playable.

I’ve tried to google the solution, but I haven’t found any results about multiple audio streams in a single video file.

Answer (score 5):

The best program for singling out audio tracks - or any others - from an MKV container is the freeware MKVtoolnix. You select/deselect the tracks by checkbox ...

https://mkvtoolnix.download/

I do not know of any official links other than the one above.

I use it on a daily basis and can verify it's ease of use for this type project.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if included link(s) breaks please [edit] these details into your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can change audio track in VLC Preference menu.

```
VLC Preference 
   Audio 
      Show All 
          Input Codec 
              Track Setting 
                   Audio Track -1
```

change -1 to 0 for audio track 1, 1 for audio track 2, save it and do convert as usual.

Don't forget to set -1 again before you quit!

Comment: Just as a thought, it might be nice if there was a bit more detail on each section (e.g. *Preferences* is found under *Tools,  Audio is a button*, *Show All* is actually the *Show settings -> All* radio button, *Input Codec* is *Input/Codecs*, *Track settings* is a section and *Audio track* is a field). Note you can make lists as well (either manually or you can start them from the editing/markdown interface).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Handbrake for this.

Download it for your platform at https://handbrake.fr/.

Once installed, click the "Source" button. Select the MKV file. It will load, and in the menus underneath "output settings" you can select audio. A list will come up with what audio tracks you want to want to extract.

Comment: Are you sure that it's possible to extract an audio track using handbrake? As it seems, [Audio only export options](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/issues/1250) was not implemented in Handbrake.

Answer (score 0):

Items needed : mkvtoolnix and inviskamkv extract

Install two software above. Next, open inviska and drag the file(s) into that. Finally, select the tracks you want to be extracted and click start  :)